# How to click on an element in the iframe?

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

In site https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo I'm trying to click on the iframe (recaptcha) and then on the button with the headphone icon. But I can not. How to do it? Where is the mistake?

```
driver.get(RECAPTCHA_PAGE_URL)
time.sleep(random.uniform(MIN_RAND, MAX_RAND))
iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
driver.switch_to_frame(iframes[0])
time.sleep(random.uniform(MIN_RAND, MAX_RAND))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark" and @role="presentation"]').click()
time.sleep(random.uniform(MIN_RAND, MAX_RAND))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@id="recaptcha-audio-button"]').click()
time.sleep(random.uniform(LONG_MIN_RAND, LONG_MAX_RAND))
```

MIN_RAND ,MAX_RAND,LONG_MIN_RAND, LONG_MAX_RAND is nums. 
Error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <iframe name="etxg0ejyszkb" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/bframe?hl=en&v=r20171129143447&k=6Le-wvkSAAAAAPBMRTvw0Q4Muexq9bi0DJwx_mJ-#etxg0ejyszkb"> stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to the iframe first. Something like this

```
    driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
```

Comment: This Iframe have #document. How to get there? @SuperStew

Comment: You should be able to find it by the Xpath as well.